# CodeFirst where is the metadata collection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to enable migrations and I'm getting the following exception:

> The item with identity 'my_table' already exists in the metadata collection.
>   Parameter name: item

This is the complete stack trace:

> System.ArgumentException: The item with identity 'my_table' already exists in the metadata collection.
>   Parameter name: item
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCollection`1.AddInternal(T item)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntitySetBaseCollection.Add(EntitySetBase item)
>      at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.EdmModelExtensions.AddAssociationSet(EdmModel model, String name, AssociationType associationType)
>      at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.NavigationPropertyMapper.Map(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, EntityType entityType, Func`1 entityTypeConfiguration)
>      at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
>      at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.NavigationPropertyMapper.Map(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, EntityType entityType, Func`1 entityTypeConfiguration)
>      at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
>      at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.<>c__DisplayClassd.<MapTypes>b__7(Type type)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 ts, Action`1 action)
>      at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.MapTypes(EdmModel model)
>      at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
>      at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ModelBeingInitialized()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetModel>b__0(XmlWriter w)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1 writeXml)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext context)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
>      at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>      at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldInitialCreate(String language, String rootNamespace)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)

This is a new database where no migrations where applied yet and there is no __MigrationHistory table located.

So where is the metadata collection located?